# What exactly happened to Yuta Gamon?

Tags: occultic-nine

**Note: This entire question is a spoiler, so as it doesn't make sense to put the entire question in a spoiler block, read at your own caution.**

---

At the end of *Occultic;Nine*, Yuta Gamon fires the unlocked Poya-Gun (revealed to be the Wardenclyffe Gun) at the Odd Eye in order to stop the New World Order from completing their mission.

It's presumed that he never makes it back to the human world (AKA is resurrected like the rest of the main cast), but what exactly happened to him?

I'm especially confused about the significance of the Sky Sensor playing staticky sounds in his father's old recording studio at the very end. Did Yuta return to the wavelength meant for the dead and in turn, get reunited with his father (again) or did he get stuck in the wavelength that the New World Order shifted to in an attempt to prevent Yuta from stopping them?

Answer (score 1):

While it's not clear what "wavelength" Yuta Gamon is on, his spirit is clearly still connected to the normal world. The final scene before the credits reveals that he's still posting on his blog, trying to earn affiliate money. I don't know if the static from the Sky Sensor means much, other than to suggest that it's still capable of connecting to the spirit wavelength, although his latest blog entry apparently has something to do with the device.

In addition, at the end of the credits, the live action shots of the pond being drained and the final brief scene showing a "Coldsleep Room" with the name Gamon Yuta on it suggests that his body has been recovered and has been cryogenically frozen. This would have put on hold the almost expired 9-minute limit on revival after death. I'm guessing they're hoping to make a sequel.

[image: He's dead set on making money, even a ghost!]

[image: COLDSLEEP ROOM -- GAMON YUTA]

Answer (score 1):

Gamon Yuuta might possibly be revived if there was to be a season 2 since based on the 9-minute limit revival, he didn't actually go past the time as to when he destroyed the facility. Aveline also said that he might come back to life in the last episode.

So, just maybe, but that's just based on my own thinking though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Sky Sensor was playing staticky sounds because it was returning some kind of feedback from the frequency it was using, probably from Yuta Gamon.

About what happened to him, he remained dead, as we could understand from the final of the last episode. About the wavelength in which he stayed, as long as he had the Sky Sensor he change wavelengths however he wishes to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the title of his blog post was something along the lines of

> [Good News] I am a Ghost.

The image quality wasn't that good so I may be wrong (also, my Japanese isn't that good)

Answer (score -1):

Gamon Yuta (a kid who was rather pathetic when he was alive), after his own death, in the last episode of this series, thanks to the advice of a fellow ghost who explain to him how to take advantage of his hidden potential, becomes Gary Stu (maybe even better) as a ghost.

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference for this?